# How to have a logo in the middle of two menu lists?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, centering

I am trying to put a logo between two menu lists, but it isnt working. I made a PSD before hand and this is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

However, I just cant accomplish this in html and css for some reason. Here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

How am I supposed to do this? It just wont work for some reason.

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu-left">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="hello" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="menu-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="portfolio" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
    div {
    display: block;
}

.nav {
    height: 64px;
    background: url(navigation_bg.png);
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.menu-left, .menu-right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.menu-left {
    left: 200px;
}

.menu-right {
    right: 200px;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
}

.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'FuturaStdBoldCondensed';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0 20px;
}

.menu-right ul li {
    float: right;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 140px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url(logo.png) center center rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

How do I get this perfectly centered?

Comment: Just insert the logo into a list item, add a class/id to that list item and style that list item appropriately. You don't need two unordered lists.

Comment: Also the width of your logo is 128px and you are specifying 140px in CSS.

Comment: @Scott That works, but how do I center it? If I take away `float:left` and replace it with `display:inline`, the logo doesnt show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I wouldn't actually separate menu into two pieces. Make it in one piece, and then set one of the middle LI to class lets say `hspace` and apply `padding-left` (or right) to that class. Then absolutely postion your logo.
2. To perfectly center the text in LI, just apply `text-align: center;` to it.

Comment: how can I perfectly center the UL itself? I cant use `display:inline` on each LI because then the logo doesnt show.

Comment: There is `display: inline-block;` property. It might do the work. But I recommend to use procedure I described above. Take a look at site that I wrote a while ago here: [link](http://www.restauracemichalov.cz/) . It uses the same technique.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/L2VrN/

I got the logo centered in between the two menus.

To do this, I put another DIV around the logo with `left:50%` and then a negative value for left on the logo to compensate for it's width.

You might have to play around with your left/right values for your menus and logo to get the positioning exactly where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to center your ul...

Remove the "margin:0 auto" from the "nav", there's no need for it as the width is 100%, and you want to center the ul.

Set the right width to the "UL" them use the 'margin: 0 auto" on it.